# Not able to create an ABI in vs code

Tags: solidity, ether, python, abi

I want to compile a smart contract on my vs code and also want to create a JSON file by using the following code at the end of my solidity code:

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file: 
json.dump(compile_sol, file)

but no file was created when I used the command *python deploy.py*. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The is because Python requires indentation for `with open`, like this:

```
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
  json.dump(compile_sol, file)
```

[You have similar question answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043860/how-to-dump-a-dict-to-a-json-file)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but actually it is a copy paste error. In my vs code I do actually have an indentation. Can you think of something else? Because the issue is still there.